# Validate Microsoft Graph acces token

Tags: php, openssl, microsoft-graph-api

I've implemented Azure AD authentication from my PHP app, using adal.js and the MS PHP SDK.

Everything works except I can't decode the access token to check if it is expired/ should be renewed.

I uploaded a certificate in the Azure Portal, but when trying to decode the access token I get a 'Signature verification failed' error.

Any hints where to look?

Comment: It's best if you actually shared a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can help you debug the issue. Otherwise all we can do is guess, and that won't get you very far.

Answer (score 0):

The access token you receive from Azure AD should have an expiresOn attribute that is the time the token expires. In my applications, I store that data and simply check if the current time is past the expireOn time

Comment: Yes, but how do you decode the token? I tried using the matching public key (used instructions on https://nicksnettravels.builttoroam.com/post-2017-01-24-verifying-azure-active-directory-jwt-tokens-aspx/), but also on jtw.io I can't seem to decode/ validate the token.